# Viewport Tag Syntax

Tags: google-chrome, safari, meta-tags, viewport

I have been looking on the web and I'm still confused on which works and does not.  I see errors on chrome when I use the semi-colon, but the iPhone recognizes it.  The comma works also without errors.  I'm wondering which one is qualified as the correct way of writing it.

Semi Colons -

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

Commas -

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" / >
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

I'm just looking for a correct interpretation of why I have this error if both work, especially why it throws an error on Chrome.

Comment: If you run iOS safari with error messaging turned on in settings, you will get a notice telling you that the semicolons are an invalid attribute value

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Commas are the correct delimiters for viewport properties. iPhone Safari (and other browsers) might be more forgiving and interpret semicolons as delimiters as well, but then you're relying on the browser's error handling.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't see this answer.  I saw it on a web site soon after I asked this question.  Forgot to add Notifications. :(

Comment: It should also be noted that the correct value for the user-scalable key is yes or no, not 1 or 0. (References: [Safari Supported Meta Tags](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html), [Chrome Revision 154568](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=154568&view=revision))

Comment: Really? https://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt-1/#user-scalable would imply otherwise.