# How to create a div in a page with its content fitting the screen irrespective of the width of the content

Tags: css, html

Is there a way using CSS3 or some javascript library that allows a webpage to have a div with content that has width greater than screen width e.g. a large image or a news letter kind of content but fits it to the screen without allowing scroll or clipping any content. Attached is an image that shows this behaviour. This has been taken from Gmail mobile website( open https://gmail.com) on iPhone Safari.

[image: See the attached image below which explains the situation.]

Comment: I figured it out, they are using a CSS3 property called -webkit-transform and setting it to scale3d(x,y,z). Where x, y, z is the scale ratio which is calculated by dividing the window width with the div's scrollwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Use the meta viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1" / >
```

[Viewport Tag Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555125/viewport-tag-syntax)

Comment: Adding this meta tag will no doubt make the page fit the screen width but it will make the whole page look zoomed out. Please look at the screen shot I have attached. The content in the div that I have marked has been zoomed out to fit the screen rest of the content on the page is in its normal state. So the problem with the meta approach is that if the page has a very large image then it will make other things like say the bin icon on the top bar in the attached image look really tiny.

Comment: I will rephrase the problem statement for you: As you can see in the attached screen shot there is a div containing some news letter kind of content and its somehow able to fit the content in the width of the screen i.e. it is able to zoom out that particular div ONLY. This ensures that other icons/content on the page looks same irrespective of the content in "the div".