# How to disable zooming in Windows Mobile?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, windows-phone-7

Is there some way of disabling zooming in Windows Mobile smartphones? For example HTC Titan.

I have this in my head html section:

```
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />
```

But I am still able to zoom in and out.

Comment: not sure if this helps, but I'm just guessing since IE is so sensitive to scripts and certain calls.  Correct syntax is with commas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555125/viewport-tag-syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

The setting you have in your question is correct and works on Windows Phone as tested on both my Nokia Lumia 900 (Tango) and Dell Venue Pro (Mango).

If you're having problems with the dynamic viewport setting you can try setting the resolution directly.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480" />
```

Reference: [Windows Team Blog: Windows Phone Viewport](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/03/14/managing-the-windows-phone-browser-viewport.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
<meta content='True' name='HandheldFriendly' />
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```